# Can't move files or folders to some positions

Tags: macos, folders, desktop, file

As you can see in the below video, I can not move files or folders to some positions on desktop. There is nothing that blocks me to move. I couldn't solve what causes this problem.

Sometimes the problem can be solved by just restarting but not always.

[image]

Disabling "Snap to Grid" is not the solution of this problem. I want my files and folders to be snapped to the grid. Please watch the GIF above. As you can see from there, the folder can be moved and snapped to grid everywhere except top-left.

What might block one of the grid spots from receiving an icon on the desktop?

Answer (score 3):

It's something I've seen before but cannot reproduce at will.
It's easiest to repro if you're dragging close to another item with a longer name, but that doesn't always seem to be the issue.

Usually it requires some combination of toggling Sort by… or Snap To Grid - though that will upset a lot of otherwise carefully-placed icons that you'd have to reset afterwards.
if you'd rather not do that, then if you hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  as you drag, it will stay where you put it [not snapped, but you can usually get it close enough by eye]

Sometimes you can clear it by enlarging the grid spacing on the desktop, or reducing the font size - then when you return it to your previous settings, the issue magically goes away.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like dragging with <kbd> Cmd ⌘ </kbd> kinda solved my problem. It's not the exact solution for my problem but yeah, that helped. Apple should've fixed this problem by now. I've been facing with this problem since macOS High Sierra (maybe even in previous versions, I didn't use them so I'm not sure). And I've seen some other people encountering the same problem, so I'm not the only one.

Comment: I can't recall how far back this issue goes. It's very intermittent but if you find a spot it doesn't like… it *damnwell* doesn't like it until you 'tweak something';) If I were a betting man, I'd bet it goes back long before El Capitan.

Answer (score -4):

Go to your Desk and right click on it.

Then go to `Sort by` and uncheck `Snap to grid`

You're welcome. With pleasure